# Icon and Image (on Assets folder) missing if removing "/' on URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I'm making an admin web with Codeigniter, but i encounter some problem and it can only triggered by removing "/" (only after hiding index.php) or adding "/" (without hiding index.php), the icon just missing and if i use an image from for profile pic the image will also missing.

*without hiding index.php and adding "/" on the url.
[image: prob1]

*after adding "/" on the last function name
[image: prob2]

here is my MY_Controller code to render page/view with template

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function render_page($content, $data = NULL)
    {
        $data['head'] = $this->load->view('sliced/head', $data, TRUE);
        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('sliced/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['js'] = $this->load->view('sliced/js', $data, TRUE);
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view($content, $data, TRUE);
        $data['sidebar'] = $this->load->view('sliced/sidebar', $data, TRUE);
        $data['modal'] = $this->load->view('sliced/modal', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('sliced/footer', $data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('sliced/template', $data);
    }
}
```

my controller

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("user_model");

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !== TRUE){
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function index()
{

    $data["user"] = $this->user_model->getAll();
    $data['controller']=$this;
    $data['curruser'] = $this->session->userdata('name');
    $data['role'] = $this->session->userdata('role');
    $this->render_page("home/home", $data);
}
}
```

this is how i call images from assets folder on view

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/noprofimage.png')?>" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
```

i appreciate any help or reply.
Thank you.

Comment: Well simply view the page source HTML from your browser to see what it is generating. That way you will have a clue. Looking is the key to finding :)

Comment: This may be because of `base_url` in your config file. Please check the console for errors

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks for the quick reply, i just trying viewing all media address from page info in firefox and i found some interesting stuff, https://i.imgur.com/0N3dpiW.png

Comment: @imoverflow thanks for the quick reply, i'll try looking on that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, and it was silly.
I just forgot using base_url to locate all the iconpack / images, guess i need to relax a bit hahaha.
Thanks to [TimBrownlaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857384/timbrownlaw) for suggesting the best way to using page source/info option.
And also thanks to [imoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11387543/imoverflow) for making sure to check any links to my assets stuff.